# org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException when read .owl file

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology

I'm usign Jena API to load a .owl file in my aplication. But when I try to read the file using the FileManager class, it throwed this exception:

> org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 26, col: 50] {E201} Multiple children of property element

I reviewed the ontology and it is ok.

Here is the code I tried:

```
public OntModel readOntology() {

    FileManager.get().getLocationMapper().addAltEntry(ontURL, ontFilePath);
    Model baseOnt = FileManager.get().loadModel(ontoURL);

    ontoModel.addSubModel(baseOnt);

    return ontoModel;
}
```

I have no idea what it could be, I think the problem is in the .owl file

Comment: Without seeing you file, how you can expect us to tell whether it's legal or not.  And is it an RDF/XML file or an OWL/XML file?  Both would be XML, and could be ".owl" files, but only one is RDF and can be read by Jena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is illegal as RDF/XML.  Note that ".owl" files may be OWL in it's own XML format.

> I think the problem is in the .owl file

Yes.